# Vamos executar um DROP [table] [tabela] e com isso gerar zero resultados na [datatable]?

Tags: debate, tags, tag-específica

## As tags

Me deparei com a tag [table](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table). No momento há 103 perguntas nela. Eis a descrição do wiki dela:

> Tag HTML utilizada para definir um tabela. Não utilize para tabelas de banco de dados.

Mas é claro que como ninguém lê os wikis, é óbvio que uma boa parte das perguntas são exatamente sobre tabelas de banco de dados. Aliás, quando uma wiki tem uma descrição do tipo *não use para tal coisa*, significa que é exatamente essa coisa que é um dos principais usos da tag.

Além disso, há alguns poucos usos dela que também não são HTML e nem banco de dados. Como por exemplo, [1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141987/132), [2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106842/132) e [3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/98835/132).

Além disso, já temos a tag [tabela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tabela) com 74 perguntas. Eis a descrição dela:

> Uma tabela HTML é uma estrutura que permite a criação de linhas e colunas usadas para disposição de listas, especificações e outros dados tabulares, além de permitir a disposição de textos e imagens através de comandos razoavelmente precisos.

Desnecessário afirmar que esta tag também está poluída com perguntas acerca de bancos de dados.

Tem também a tag [html-table](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-table), com 21 perguntas:

> No que se refere ao HTML, as tabelas são usadas para exibir dados de forma tabular.

Fui verificar a tag [tabela-html](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tabela-html) e não há nada. Na minha opinião esse nome seria melhor que qualquer um dos três acima.

Para o lado do banco de dados, temos a tag [tabela-banco-de-dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tabela-banco-de-dados), com 66 perguntas no momento. Eis a descrição:

> Em um sistema de gerenciamento de banco de dados relacional (RDBMS) uma tabela organiza as informações em linhas e colunas. Não use a tag "tabela" para perguntas não relacionadas esse assunto.

Ainda temos a tag [datatable](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatable), com 67 perguntas. Entretanto, eis a descrição dela:

> O termo "DataTable" é ambíguo. Em .NET , é uma classe que representa uma tabela de dados na memória. No framework baseado em componente MVC como JSF e Wicket, é um componente de interface que torna dinamicamente uma tabela HTML com base em uma coleção. Para jQuery DataTables plugin, por favor, use a tag [jquery-datatables](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables).

E é claro que há perguntas sobre [jquery-datatables](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables) lá [1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118903/132), [2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106600/132).

Ou seja, pela própria descrição se vê que é uma tag mal-definida. Uma tag ambígua não serve para organizar o site, e sim para desorganizar o site.

## Minha proposta:

O primeiro passo seria separar as perguntas com tabelas de banco de dados na tag [tabela-banco-de-dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tabela-banco-de-dados), as de HTML na [tabela-html](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tabela-html) ou então na [html-table](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-table) ou simplesmente removidas das perguntas em que não acrescentam nada. As que sobrarem vão para [jquery-datatables](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables), [jtable](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jtable), etc.

Quanto a tag [datatable](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatable), as perguntas de lá também seriam separadas em [jquery-datatables](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables) e algumas tag novas a serem criadas, tais como [jsf-datatable](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf-datatable), [.net-datatable](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-datatable), [wicket-datatable](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wicket-datatable) (se já existirem parecidas, alguém me avise, por favor) ou simplesmente removidas das perguntas em que não acrescentam nada.

Por fim, as tags [table](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table), [tabela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tabela) e [datatable](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatable) correm o risco de serem criadas novamente. Por isso, é importante que elas sejam mandadas para queimar nas profundezas do inferno para todo o sempre e por toda a eternidade sendo acrescentadas na lista negra de tags do SOpt e lá permanecendo até o fim dos tempos. Deste modo, nunca mais algum pobre e tolo mortal poderá conjurá-las e acabar por trazê-las do submundo das trevas de volta para o mundo dos vivos.

Comment: Essa eu estava deixando para o final porque é das mais enroladas, mas que bom que colocou. Vamos ver o que o pessoal acha. Eu acho que o caminho é mais ou menos esse. Só para informar que essencialmente não há *tag* proibida no site e até onde eu sei os devs, que são os únicos que podem fazer isso não farão para qualquer caso. Nós teremos que testar o que eles farão. Pra ajudar, o SO tem a *tag* `table`. Isso pode ser um complicador. Se uma *tag* não for proibida, só tem duas soluções.Colocar na descrição para não usar (não funciona), ou criar sinônimo (cria confusão).Vamos ver outras opiniões

Comment: Não consigo dizer se a tag `table` tem sentido de existir ou não, mas se tiver, julgo que o primeiro passo seria fazer a distinção entre *html* e banco de dados.  Colocar "Não usar" ou criar sinónimo pode "não funcionar" ou "criar confusão" para alguns(muitos talvez),  mas isso não é razão para não ser feito.(@bigown Penso que era isso que quis dizer, certo?.)

Comment: @ramaral isso mesmo. Só estou colocando as possibilidades e consequências. Um dos motivos que escolhi começar pelas *tags* menos problemáticas é que podemos testar algumas soluções para ver se funciona. Nas *tags* "menores" fica mais fácil refazer se algo não der certo. Mas temos que tentar soluções. O que não pode é deixar bagunçado. E eu imaginava que teria uma participação baixa, mas ter 3 ou 4 decidindo tudo isso é algo que faz pensar em algo que vai além do assunto de *tags*. Tem alguma coisa errada.

Comment: @bigown É, já tinha pensado nisso também, "cadê" os outros?

Comment: @bigown Dá para julgar pela votação. Não vejo gente votando contra. E normalmente quando alguém é contra isso, esse alguém no mínimo posta algum comentário ou vota contra.

Comment: meus irmãos, foi fds tenham calma...

Comment: @JorgeB. tem perguntas dessas de *tags* que está aí há 3 semanas e não chegou a meia dúzia de pessoas participando, literalmente. Essa semana eu voltarei ter mais tempo e vou começar fazer o que tem que ser feito.

Comment: @bigown força com isso! Sei que não necessita, mas tem todo o meu apoio. Se necessitar de ajuda diga.

Comment: Sem necessidade nenhuma dessa pergunta!

Comment: @sysWOW32 Gostaria de explicar melhor o seu ponto de vista?

Comment: @bigown entretanto esqueci-me de passar por aqui de novo, acho que o Victor tem toda a razão, para solucionar os problemas é só fazer sinónimos para a tag que queremos que permaneça, temos feito isso no PL e tem dado resultado.

Comment: @JorgeB. preciso elaborar mais sobre isso, mas pode ser que funcione lá que tem poucos termos, pouca ambiguidade. Aqui eu acho que seria um festival de uso errado. E não acho que o Victor propôs o que você está falando.

Comment: @bigown acho que devias ver melhor como funciona, tu escreves "table" na tag e o que aparece na realidade é "html-table", por exemplo. Pode ser que as pessoas assim tenham mais cuidado. Ou pelo menos será mais perceptível a má utilização, digo eu...

Comment: @JorgeB. exatamente isso. Imagine aparecer `htm-table` em uma pergunta de SQL. As pessoas não vão começar ter cuidado por causa disso. Tem casos bem perceptíveis que ninguém muda. Na verdade o cara vai xingar a UX do site, e até com razão. Não digo que não possa ser feito, mas em casos onde 99% seja aquilo. Um exemplo **talvez** fazer que o `bootstrap* seja sinônimo de `twitter-bootstrap`. Já tem uma discussão dessa *tag* que não se chegou a uma conclusão.

Comment: @bigown talvez tenhas razão, mas então a única solução que vejo é, para já separar tudo e apagar as que não interessam, e ir fazendo manutenção, ou daqui a uns tempo vir para aqui de novo discutir. Não vejo uma solução definitiva em cima da mesa.

Comment: @JorgeB. de fato algo mágico que resolve tudo não acho que terá, o que eu acho é que as pessoas precisam adotar suas *tags* preferidas e ficar arrumando logo que postam algo. Infelizmente não vejo outra solução. Até vejo, mas algo radical e que teria outros problemas e quase ninguém gostaria :D

Answer (score 2):

Pra variar eu ia postar como comentário mas ficou grande demais... :)

---

> Antes de mais nada, por favor, desculpem a minha opinião assim tão direta,
>   **mas eu acho que a comunidade em geral olha para as tags de forma
>   equivocada.**

Tá, na descrição da tag [table](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table) está escrito algo do tipo "*É só pra HTML! Não use para outra coisa!*", e muitos já perceberam que isso não funciona. E não funciona porque a descrição de qualquer tag é implicitamente intuitiva por si só (é um signo, na semiótica), de forma que o usuário lê e entende com base no que está escrito e também com base no contexto em que ele se encontra na hora que faz uma postagem. Esperar que quem vai empregar uma tag deva considerar todos os contextos possivelmente existentes ou mesmo ler a descrição que os limita é trabalhoso e simplesmente improdutivo (se não for de fato inviável).

A tag [table](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table) é suficientemente genérica para englobar *qualquer tipo de tabela*, afinal é isso que a palavra inglesa "*table*" (e sua correspondente em português "tabela") significa(m). A primeira pergunta é: por que raios alguém julgou que seria interessante limitar seu uso apenas ao contexto HTML?

Além disso, tags são apenas classificadores de conteúdo cuja intenção primordial é indexação das postagens num metafórico e vasto oceano de conteúdo. Ou seja, sua intenção é facilitar que o conteúdo relevante (para quem precisa, em seu próprio contexto) seja encontrado em buscas. Logo, a segunda pergunta é: por que temos tanta preocupação em limitar ou conduzir a indexação por parte dos usuários?

Apenas para citar um exemplo real, recentemente eu coloquei a tag [jogos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jogos) em uma pergunta que solicitava ajuda com o uso de temporizadores (*timers*), porque o AP indicava o contexto de jogos. Outro usuário retirou a tag porque a julgou desnecessária. Ok, afinal é trabalho colaborativo e as opiniões divergem mesmo. Mas, que mal aquela tag fazia ali naquela pergunta? Ela não estava colocada de forma errônea (por exemplo, uma tag de [javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) em uma pergunta sobre [java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)), pois fazia sentido no contexto. Além do mais, se fosse mantida, poderia facilitar que outro usuário encontrasse esse conteúdo numa busca futura, simplesmente se ele também tivesse em mente no momento de busca o seu conteúdo de [timers](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/timers) + [jogos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jogos).

Enfim, o meu ponto é que há problemas sim, eu concordo. Mas eu realmente não acho que seja a existência da tag [table](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table), e sim a limitação que foi imposta a ela na sua descrição.

> Uma última coisa pra se pensar e discutir: dentre as duas opções A e B
>   a seguir, qual faz mais sentido?
>
> A. Ter muitas tags super específicas (como [html-table](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-table) ou
>   [.net-mvc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-mvc)) e assim fazer com que a busca pelas/utilização das
>   tags seja igualmente específica.
>
> B. Ter poucas tags gerais (como [html](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), [table](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table),
>   [.net](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) e [mvc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc)) e assim permitir que a especificidade da
>   indexação do conteúdo seja feita pelo uso complementar das tags.
>
> São duas opções distintas, cada uma com as suas vantagens e dificuldades. Mas,
>   qual é mais natural para os usuários? Eu acredito que seja a B.

Comment: Bom, pra falar sobre tudo isso eu precisa de uma longa resposta e não um comentário, o que já complicou, porque isso já é uma resposta (embora pareça pergunta). Sabendo que vai causar mais confusão que esclarecimento: a) é interessante limitar o uso para que ela tenha relevância, se alguém for procurar por algo e lá tiver um monte de ruído, ela não serve para muita coisa; b) como classificadora não pode deixar o usuário colocar o que bem entende, tem que ter relação com o conteúdo, isso talvez poderia acontecer se *tag* fosse meramente iuma informação acessória;

Comment: c) a *tag* `jogos` é uma das mais mal usadas e pode até ser considerada uma meta-tag, ela dificilmente pode ser usada sozinha, o que a desqualifica (sei que cabe um debate), quase sempre esse tipo de contexto é irrelevante para o problema (*tags* devem ser relevantes para o conteúdo, não para o gosto do usuário ou algo colateral ao conteúdo), mas essa é outra questão (mau uso); d) o padrão adotado na rede é ter muitas *tags*. tem mais de 50K no SO http://stackoverflow.com/tags

Comment: @bigown Bom, foi o que eu disse (e não se ofenda, por favor), mas eu acho que é justamente essa a visão equivocada das tags. a) Relevância depende do contexto de quem faz a busca pelo conteúdo. Não sou eu ou você quem vai julgar isso. b) Sim, claro. Mas é mais fácil já sugerir para o usuário tags mais fáceis do que tags específicas demais. c) Meta tag não existe. Tag é tag. Você considera como contexto o conteúdo da postagem, sendo que eu argumento que o contexto é *o da busca*. Aí jaz a distinção primária. d) ah, eu amo tanto quando algo ruim é justificado com "é o padrão" #sqn rs

Comment: Então quem vai julgar? Se fizer como você quer, qual o critério para escolher as 5 *tags* que podem ser colocadas, porque se for tentar pegar tudo o que a pessoa pode procurar, 5 é bem pouco. Por isso esse uso de *tag* não funciona. Você quer inventar uma padrão novo, ok, mas esse é o padrão. Boa sorte em mudar todas as perguntas para ficar do jeito que pretende, e manter tudo em ordem  o tempo todo (temos algumas *tags* problemáticas, passaremos ter problema com tudo) e instruir todo mundo fazer buscas de forma diferente. https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Comment: @bigown Quem *deveria* julgar é a comunidade. Afinal, não é por isso que as tags são editáveis por outras pessoas além do AP? A limitação a 5 é outra discussão, eu admito, mas que eu também discordo veementemente (porém sei que aí esbarramos mais uma vez no "by design").

Comment: @bigown Sobre as tais meta-tags, no link que você me mandou (obrigado!) eu notei particularmente essa passagem: "*These are tags that don't say anything by themselves - you can't tell what the question is about unless they're paired with some other tag (or several of them)*.". Justamente. E é aí que está o meu ponto: talvez o sistema tenha começado errado em tornar as tags específicas demais ao invés de estimular o "pareamento". Mas eu sei que não vou conseguir mudar nada mesmo. Só estava exercendo o meu direito de argumentar contra esse ideal. :)

Comment: Nós somos a comunidade. Nós estamos aqui discutindo isso. Se quer debater uma mudança radical, pode abrir um debate para isso, eu já sei e acho que já aprendeu qual será o resultado. Então eu estou trabalhando com o que a realidade nos impõe. O padrão adotado funciona para o mecanismo atual e a forma como as perguntas foram classificadas até então. Na forma que está propondo sempre terá que ter alguém garantindo que todas *tags* necessárias estão presentes para a pergunta seja achada,é a festa das meta-tags*.Hoje isso só é necessário em alguns,não tão poucos casos, um erro não causa grande mal

Comment: Estamos lendo aquele artigo de forma diferente. Lá diz que uma *tag* `table` não pode depender de uma `html` para fazer sentido do que se trata ali. Se me conhece, sabe que o importante é debater.

Comment: @bigown Olha, apesar da minha reclamação implícita (eu sei, desculpe), eu não estou propondo uma mudança radical. Essencialmente o que eu disse em relação à pergunta do AP foi para manter a tag [tag:table] e só remover da descrição dela a especificidade em relação ao HTML. Você insiste que ela é uma "meta" tag (o que eu discordo, pois qualquer tag poderia ser dita como "meta" se tiver outra ainda mais específica), mas que mal ela faz realmente em existir?

Comment: @bigown É? Em qual passagem?

Comment: @bigown Aliás, fazer sentido é do ponto de vista da "caracterização do conteúdo" (segundo a minha interpretação de texto do que está ali escrito), e assim as duas formas "html-table" e "html" + "table" são igualmente válidas. Só que a segunda é mais genérica e reutilizável. Eu até entendo o fato de que não vai mudar, mas você não está me convencendo em dizer que eu estou errado só por estar.

Comment: @bigown Ah, e eu não estou dizendo que você ou eu estamos julgando ou sendo pouco propícios ao debate. Quando eu disse que "quem deveria julgar é a comunidade", minha intenção era descrever que *o ideal* (talvez utópico por vários motivos, mas o ideal - na minha opinião) é que as tags fossem auto-organizadas conforme as pessoas fizessem e, principalmente, localizassem as perguntas.

Comment: Eu disse que estamos lendo o artigo de forma diferente, então todo o artigo diz isso, não de forma direta, ele diz qual é o problema da *tag* que depende de outra. Eu não disse que está errado, disse apenas que hoje o mecanismo e o uso no SO e os quase 3 anos do SOpt sempre foi assim. Acho um pouco tarde para mudar porque não é algo que você possa mudar só daqui pra frente, tem que arrumar tudo o que existe, o que é impraticável.E acho mais difícil manter organizado depois pelo que já disse anteriormente.Pelo menos agora ficou claro que está falando de algo utópico.É 1 bom debate em outro post

Comment: @bigown Eu já li o artigo duas vezes. Além do fato de que ele cita tags bem específicas, as tags utilizadas nele não descrevem conteúdo da mesma forma que "table" faz. Aliás, eu admiti que todo o ideal talvez seja utópico, o que não quer dizer que o "processo" parcialmente não pudesse ser melhorado. Mas, enfim, se você acha que esse é mesmo um bom debate para outro post, então vamos encerrar por aqui.

Comment: @bigown Desculpem o meu pragmatismo, mas esta discussão é inútil: **1)** Só é possível usar 5 tags. **2)** Não use "tags meta" nas perguntas: ***2a)*** Se a tag não pode funcionar como a única tag de uma pergunta, provavelmente é uma "tag meta", ***2b)*** Se a tag normalmente significar coisas diferentes para pessoas diferentes, provavelmente é uma "tag meta". [Fonte:O que são tags e como devo usá-las?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: @ramaral 1) Ok. Como eu disse, é *by design*. Mas não quer dizer que resolva o "problema" de ter uma infinidade de tags inúteis. 2a) Se é assim, por que não se limita em 1 tag? Essa heurística, embora útil, não pode ser tomada como verdade absoluta. 2b) Perfeito. Mas eu entendo o conceito descrito como "tag não específica", e não como "tag meta" (que seria uma tag a respeito de outra). O meu ponto era justamente que fazemos errado em garantir a *especificidade* pela tag ao invés de pelo uso conjunto de tags. A discussão pode até ser inútil (ou utópica) pelo item 1, não pelos demais.

Comment: Luiz e @bigown Acho que esse debate todo vale a abertura de uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Os seus argumentos são válidos, por isso reformulo: Esta discussão só tem sentido se for no âmbito de uma proposta de alterar o que está institucionalizado.

Comment: @ramaral Ok, você tem razão. :)

Comment: O que eu quis dizer, com o primeiro comentário, é que é assim que está definido e temos de viver com isso(o @bigown explicou porquê). De qualquer forma, o meu entendimento do uso das tags não permite dizer qual das duas faz mais sentido, eu até diria que, por serem tão radicais, nenhuma faz sentido. Você mesmo diz que ambas têm "vantagens e dificuldades". O que faz sentido, encontra-se num ponto algures entre elas. As questões que têm vindo a ser levantadas sobre determinadas tags, têm o propósito de encontrar esse ponto.

Comment: Eu entendi, @ramaral. Mesmo. Obrigado pela ajuda. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira desculpa mas eu não entendi qual é a vantagem de ter uma tag [tag:table] que se uso em tudo que é "table" no mundo? Se eu for pesquisar pela tag table vão me aparecer um sem número de perguntas que não me vão ajudar em nada. Podes me explicar qual é a vantagem de ser assim como dizes?

Comment: @JorgeB. A vantagem é para o usuário que for marcar a pergunta com a tag. Ele não precisaria gastar muito tempo refletindo se a tag é a correta (se "aquela" é só pra HTML e ele queria se referir a SQL, por exemplo). Isso evitaria também que novas tags levemente similares fossem criadas pela mesma dificuldade em saber qual tag usar. A busca só por "table" realmente retornaria muita coisa, mas isso seria facilmente solucionado por composição de tags (que, de fato, é a forma natural de buscar conteúdo: table + sql, por exemplo).

Comment: @JorgeB. Mas, foi como o colegas bem argumentaram: por melhor que essa ideia talvez fosse, o sistema já segue outra abordagem desde a sua criação, de forma que uma mudança agora seria muito difícil (se não impossível).

Comment: @LuizVieira mas eu acho que as tags são mesmo para isso, são antes para fazer uma pré filtragem do conteúdo e não para facilitar o autor na hora de tagar, para isso mais valia não ter nada. Mais vale ser mais criarem novas tags e depois nos resolvermos do que por toda a farinha no mesmo saco. Pela sua ordem de ideia, como é tudo farinha do mesmo saco, então bastavam as tags de linguagem e pouco mais. Pelo menos é o meu entender sobre para que servem as tags, para ajudar a "tipar" conteúdo.

Comment: @JorgeB. Não foi bem isso que eu quis dizer. Concordo contigo de que o uso de tags é primordialmente facilitar a indexação e a busca. Mas meu ponto é de que tags mais genéricas, que seriam usadas na indexação e na busca *por combinação* (tags combinadas) ao invés de *por especificidade* (tags muito específicas), adicionalmente facilitariam o rotulamento por parte do autor e tenderiam a reduzir o número de tags no sistema (o que também facilitaria sua gestão).

Comment: Mas sabes que há mais sistemas no site que utilizam tags, como tags favoritas, vou colocar "table" como tag favorita se estiver ligada a tudo que for tabelas? E também podes clicar diretamente na tag para ver as perguntas sobre ela, deixaria de ter uso segundo a tua ideia. E por último as medalhas de tag seriam curriqueiras, facilmente conseguiras ouro numa tag "table".

Comment: @JorgeB. Sei, sim. Tá tudo incluído no que o bigown bem argumentou anteriormente a respeito de ser utópico de se mudar. Existiriam soluções alternativas (poderia ser possível, por exemplo, favoritar "combinações" de tags), mas isso não vai mudar no sistema então não compensa ficar discutindo. De todas as formas, acho que ainda vale tomar(mos) algum cuidado com especificidade demais. :)

Answer (score -7):

Deleta e faz de novo!

Eu acho que se a tag supracitada estiver com outra tag, como por exemplo sql, óbvio trata-se se um uso com banco de dados, agora se não têm nenhuma outra tag então trata do mesmo caso que você comentou, mas pela sintaxe me parece mais coisa de jquery.

Não sei dizer, não pesquisei sobre o assunto e você me pareceu meio vago abrindo esse post, está parecendo que quer ser polêmico: olha se o cara esquecer de colocar tag sql vamos achar que é html... Ou isso ou aquilo!

Ainda não entendo porquê, mesmo as pessoas não tendo domínio sobre determinado assunto querem debater sobre assuntos desconhecidos impondo suas opiniões, se quer organizar o Tópico por tag tem que colocar todas que facilitem as pesquisas.

Comment: As tags devem ser sobre o problema e não sobre tudo, por exemplo estou com um erro no javascript, mas meu site usa php, html, css, css3, mysql e então você acha que eu devo por todas estas tags? Claro que não. O meta aqui é para resolver problemas que as pessoas no site que tem experiencia estão tentando melhorar e ajudar, para facilitar a vida de todo mundo, eu li o poste do Vitor e me parece muita coisa plausível sim, tem muita tag sem sentido, tag redundante, tag que deveria virar "sinonimo". Espero que tenha boa vontade em entender meu comentário como uma orientação sobre o site.

Comment: Spencer esta resposta é referente à pergunta ou à resposta do Luiz?

Comment: Jorge, ele começou com o Título drop[database] mas pulou o assunto para tag, me limitei em opnar sobre tab, não sendo exatamente uma resposta, mas um ponto de vista somente!
eu até já havia preparado algumas soluções para recriar ou zerar somente os ponteiros, mas não foi o foco da questão. Não compreendi se ele quer falar de tag mas começa com DROP TABLE [database]. Vá direto ao assunto e deixe de carregar pedras desnecessárias.

Comment: Pois é Guilherme Nascimento, eu estava justo procurando MYSQL e achei este POST IRRELEVANTE, irrelevante e sem sentido, consulte a documentação de tag do SO stackoverflow.com/tag.
Me pareceu meio confusa demais a organização do assunto.

Comment: Outra coisa importante, vc Guilherme mencionou justamente meu caso, eu tenho um sistema que estou concluindo para meu curso da faculdade, em php, css, javascript e mysql, e o problema de implementação em javascript, mas mencionei com todas as tag menos o mysql pois ali não existe problema algum em banco de dados e para localizar o problema, e tratar o assunto com foco exclusivo, no caso ainda não sei lidar com as citações e ao inserir a sintaxe php que precisava inserir um alert em jscriptem não ficou bem colocada, em minutos fechei a questão com a melhor resposta, objetividade leva ao sucesso

Comment: Outra coisa que acho desprezível, são essas edições que dizem 'favorecer' o entendimento, Me parece que não compreendem a importância da coesão textual e tentam 'arrumar' para seu próprio entendimento, deixando de lado 'pistas' importantes inerentes ao mundo da pergunta. <<DELETE>> for -->> editada 5/09 às 0:20

Comment: @SpencerEkroth o título é em forma de piada, usado o drop do sql para fazer uma piada com as tags, mas sim o assunto são as tags. mas já entendi que respondeste á pergunta

Comment: @SpencerEkroth O título é uma piadinha mesmo, tal como [Vamos desclassificar a tag class](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4469/132) ou [Vamos "desconfigurar" a tag configuração?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5274/132) ou [O fluxo de uso das tags de Stream está correto?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5281/132), entre outras.

Comment: Quanto a sua opinião, a ideia de tags é poder classificar perguntas. Ou seja, se eu quiser encontrar perguntas sobre SQL, basta eu olhar para a tag [sql]. O que você está propondo meio que faz esse esquema não funcionar, pois a efetividade de uma tag passa a depender da presença ou ausência das demais tags.

Comment: @SpencerEkroth respondendo ao comentário, raramente a pessoa não sabe em qual tecnologia é problema, agora postar tag CSS aonde o problema é JS só porque se trata de front-end é um baita absurdo, vc deve entender a distancia de um engano comum entre de um iniciante para algo que nada tem haver com o problema. Exemplo se o problema é no mysql e a pessoa esta usando php, mesmo que o problema seja inteiramente com a query, ainda sim é valido deixar a tag php se o resultado no output é nele. Agora se é um problema javascript e adiciono a tag CSS não fará sentido algum, espero que tenha entendido.

Comment: @SpencerEkroth algum problema com a edição que eu fiz? Não se esqueça que este site tem com um dos princípios ser colaborativo.

Comment: desculpe minha ignorância mas não entendi nada desse post

Comment: @SpencerEkroth para resumir, eu acho que talvez você não entenda o uso das tags por não ter muita experiencia com o site, talvez você só venha a entender o porque das necessidades e como funciona o META conforme ganhar experiencia no uso, as coisas aqui não foram idealizadas aleatoriamente, muitas ferramentas do site ganharam "formato" do jeito que são hoje por necessidade, desde o stackoverflow em ingles e superuser.com (os primeiros sites da SE), não tem nada de desprezível, tudo tem um motivo, nada aqui é por acaso, espero que entenda como uma critica construtiva ;)

Comment: tranquilho, mas muitas discussões ainda são do campo da semiótica. se me entende.