# Sugestão: Blacklist de tags

Tags: novo-recurso, tags

**É apenas uma sugestão para o futuro**, eu sei das dificuldades de implementar um sistema assim, só estou deixando como "sugestão mesmo".

Para alguns nem é tanto problema, para quem passa o dia ajudando no site as vezes é um grande incomodo, exemplos de situações:

- [A tag error deveria existir?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2516/3635)
- [Mudar a tag [error], [erro] para [gerenciamento-erro]?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6151/3635)
- [É um [erro] ter esta tag](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6115/3635)
- [Podemos remover estas tags?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5664/3635)
- [Vamos executar um DROP [table] [tabela] e com isso gerar zero resultados na [datatable]?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5337/3635)

A ideia é que tivéssemos um lugar para poder criar uma **blacklist** de tags, por exemplo (escrevi todas `error`, mas é apenas exemplo, cada um seria uma tag):

[image: Exemplo]

**Obviamente** que passaria por triagem ou até mesmo aprovação de moderadores, mas isto é relativo, a ideia é simples, um local para sugerir tags para serem bloqueadas, isso não é uma sugestão para o SOpt e sim para qualquer site da rede, pretendo postar no Metão assim que possivel, só que ver o que acham da ideia, ou talvez alguém da staff que cuida do site veja aqui e analise a sugestão para um possivel futuro uso ou não.

Comment: Acho que existe algo assim já, mas só os devs da Stack Exchange têm acesso.

Comment: Tive uma ideia assim ontem, ia postar agora, mas parece que *alguém* já postou =). Seria legal mesmo fazer um post corredor da morte, para podermos agrupar as tags que deveriam ser eliminadas.

Comment: Não sei direito o que eu acho, mas vale a pena ser debatido. Meu principal receio é a aplicação tão permanente de um filtro assim acabar causando mais problemas do que resolve. Nessa linha, o [aumento da reputação mínima](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5094) para criar tags já serve como um bom impedidor. E isso já está sendo estudado - só precisamos chegar num número que faça sentido.

Comment: Também acho que o aumento da rep minima seria mais que o suficiente @Gabe.

Comment: De fato já existe, @Renan. Tentei criar uma tag "error" no SOen, e deu um... erro.

Answer (score 6):

No SOen existe esse conceito de lista negra, então é algo que já existe no software da StackExchange. Pessoalmente, tenho algumas discordâncias em relação a forma como eles trabalham com isso, mas é bem melhor que nada. Solicitações no meta dele para colocar tags em listas negras são bem comuns, por exemplo:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351809/540552

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348131/540552

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342951/540552

No caso, as tags vão à lista negra de forma reativa, e não proativa. E esse processo ocorre sempre de forma manual.

Em geral, entram na lista negra as tags que já foram esvaziadas e eliminadas e acabam sendo recriadas, tendo então que ser novamente esvaziadas e eliminadas. Quando esse processo de limpeza faz-se necessário de acontecer por duas ou mais vezes, tal como ocorre com as nossas tags [erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erro) e [error](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/error), a tag passa a ser considerada passível de ser banida.

Aliás, a tag [error](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/error) está banida no SOen. Veja o que ocorre quando alguém tenta criar uma pergunta com essa tag por lá:

[image: The 'error' tag nis not allowed.]

Como disse, esse processo não é perfeito. Atualmente, ele é reservado apenas aos desenvolvedores da StackExchange (veja mais [aqui](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125812/176034) e [aqui](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124504/176034)), e a única coisa que os moderadores podem fazer é <s>encher o saco</s>, ops, quero dizer, pedir carinhosamente para os desenvolvedores da StackExchange adicionar as tags à lista negra.

Acredito que a StackExchange deveria dar aos moderadores o poder de colocar (e tirar) tags na lista negra. Se o problema é a possibilidade de causar um desastre, bastaria limitar para que apenas tags já devidamente esvaziadas pudessem ser colocadas na lista negra. Isso não é algo que deveria ser demanda para os desenvolvedores colocarem manualmente no sistema.

Quanto a possibilidade de algum moderador fazer alguma besteira com a lista negra, acho que essa preocupação é paranoica e de pouca relevância na prática, pois eles já têm o poder de fazer besteiras bem maiores que essa se quiserem e isso é algo que pode facilmente ser vigiado e auditado.

Por outro lado, enquanto os desenvolvedores não implementam esse recurso, não nos resta muita opção que não seja reinvidicar a eles a adição de algumas tags na lista negra do SOpt. Aumentar a reputação mínima para criar tags também ajuda.

Answer (score 3):

Veremos os prós e contras deste atual sistema:

## Prós

- Favoritar uma tag.
- É exibido com uma tonalidade amarela uma pergunta com seu interesse.
- Organização.
- Identificar sobre o que se trata a pergunta.

## Contras

- Qualquer erro de digitação, uma nova tag é criada.
- Muitos registros de Tags desaceleram os servidores, afetando o desempenho do site.
- Muitas tags inúteis são criadas todos os dias.
- Um assunto se divide em dez tags diferentes, confundindo o usuário.
- 20% das discussões do SOptMeta é discutindo a existência duma tag inútil.
- A reputação para criar uma tag ainda é muito baixa.

## O que poderia ser feito?

Como o Guilherme Nascimento disse, criar um blacklist iria ter que armazenar vários sufixos e vários prefixos para o usuário não criar uma tag.

Suponha que criem essa lista negra. E por acaso esquecem de acrescentar [duvida-duvidosa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duvida-duvidosa) como um item, vem alguém e cria uma pergunta com a tag [duvida-duvidosa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duvida-duvidosa) (ao menos que essa blacklist tenha muitas regras para criação, mas isso iria usar muito processador e tempo gasto dos desenvolvedores para criar uma blacklist tão inteligente assim).

Minha sugestão é, do mesmo jeito que uma parcela de usuários do SOpt precisa de uma certa reputação para cancelar uma publicação de baixa qualidade, os mesmos poderiam aprovar ou desaprovar a criação de uma tag, e a partir de uma reputação consideravelmente alta, criar tags diretamente, pois já teriam noção de como criar uma tag.

Em suma, minha sugestão é a seguinte: **reputação para aprovar/desaprovar criação de tags** na fila de análise, como desaprovar uma publicação tardia, e também uma **reputação consideravelmente alta para criar diretamente uma tag**, sem necessidade de aprovação.

Comment: Os prós ainda existiriam com a mudança xD

Comment: Sim. Não iriamos revogar a existência das tags atuais, só iriamos dar uma boa limpeza.

Comment: Não concordo 100% com isso, mas acho o sistema de *tags* quebrado, eu queria fazer um post, mas ou falta tempo ou falta inspiração. Não tenho muitas esperanças mais, ou porque acho que a SE gosta do sistema atual, ou pq eles não conseguem mais implantar todas demandas com a agilidade de antes. Algumas coisas precisariam ser bem mudadas. E algumas coisas a comunidade precisaria ajudar. Eu acho que um número médio de *tags*  é o ideal, e pra arrumar isso dá muito trabalho e quase ninguém quer ajudar. Acho que mudar o limite pra criação de *tags* tinha que ter ocorrido há muito tempo. É simples.

Comment: Um sistema de lista negra que até existe em certa medida ajudaria. Aumentar limite ajudaria. Ter um sistema de aprovação ajudaria muito, talvez nem precisasse do limite pra criar, pelo menos poderia ser bem baixo. Até eu já digitei errado e criou *tag* errada.