# Qual o proposito da tag cpu?

Tags: debate

Por que tem uma tag [cpu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cpu), se Cpu é um componente de hardware? E pergunto isso porque ela não tem uma descrição ainda, acredito que precisamos o mais rápido possivel adicionar uma descrição a ela, senão daqui a pouco eu mesmo vou usar ela pra perguntar "Qual cpu eu devo comprar?" kkk. Qual o proposito dessa tag?

Comment: Vc mesmo pode sugerir uma [recomendação para esta tag](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/4688). O fato dela ser um componente de hardware não significa que ela não deva existir aqui, existe perguntas a respeito de programação que envolve esta tag. E o propósito dela é para perguntas relacionadas a CPU, e que seja relacionada a programação ou alguma ferramenta de desenvolvimento de software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As tags não são criadas previamente, elas são criadas por qualquer um que tenha 300 pontos de score, a qualquer momento e por este motivo é que temos algumas tags consideradas inúteis, temos muitos problemas com tags até o momento, exemplos:

- [A tag error deveria existir?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2516/3635)
- [Mudar a tag [error], [erro] para [gerenciamento-erro]?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6151/3635)
- [É um [erro] ter esta tag](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6115/3635)
- [Podemos remover estas tags?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5664/3635)
- [Vamos executar um DROP [table] [tabela] e com isso gerar zero resultados na [datatable]?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5337/3635)

Aproveite e de uma lida nestas postagens:

- [Aumentar reputação necessária pra se criar tags](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5094/3635)
- [Sugestão: Blacklist de tags](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6152/3635)

Elas são sugestões de medidas para tentar resolver, mesmo que paliativamente, o problema.

### Pra resumir

Nenhuma tag quando é criada tem uma definição de uso especifica, por isto existe os campos em cada tag:

> Recomendação de uso (fragmento)

E

> Wiki de Tag

Ou seja nem sempre a tag vai ser boa pois as tags são criadas por pessoas diferentes, até pessoas que **NÃO ENTENDEM** o **escopo do site** e acabam por criar tags que também seriam "off-topic" ou simplesmente sem recomendação de uso específico, então geralmente só usuários que entendem melhor o sistema costumam colaborar para criar ou "matar" as tags desnecessárias.

É importante saber que as tags existem enquanto existirem perguntas associadas, se não existir em nenhuma pergunta, mesmo que ela tenha "Wiki" ela será *"removida"* do sistema automaticamente nas limpezas automáticas que ocorrem de tempos em tempos.